# Floating pane behaviour on resize border

Tags: dojo, containers, floating, dijit.layout

I'm new to Dojo. I created a jsfiddle to illustrate my question: jsfiddle.net/xQF7P

It doesn't show exactly what happens but it's close enough.

If you click on the purple area, a floating pane is created and added to the center region content pane.

However, the moment the border container is resized, either the browser window or using the splitter (which in jsfiddle doen't appear), the floating pane gets sized to 0, top and left 0. In the jsfiddle it will seem as if it disappeared but in my real example you can see just the resize handle as if it was docked to the top:0 left:0 inside the center region.

Thanks in advance. 
Pablo

Comment: Pablo, can you post some code also.

Comment: Floating pane doesn't understand being in a container; it never checks its parent node for sizing information.

I've hacked my own floating pane before to make it resize properly in the situations I needed it to, but it won't work as you want it to out of the box.

Comment: @Sergio - it's all in the jsfiddle, the <body> is empty.

Comment: zclark could you please post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Floating pane doesn't understand being in a container; it never checks its parent node for sizing information. I've hacked my own floating pane before to make it resize properly in the situations I needed it to, but it won't work as you want it to out of the box.